# DataTable Initial Sort Only

Tags: javascript, datatable

I have a table and I want to display the table with column 1 ordered asc.

```
$("#table").DataTable({
    "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
});
```

This works great, however, I would like to turn off the sorting mechanism after this initial `order`.

```
$("#table").DataTable({
    "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
    "ordering": false
});
```

But this removes the inital sorting mechanism as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove click event listeners from table header, so when user clicks nothing will happen.

```
$('#table th').unbind().css('cursor', 'auto');
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I face this situation I simply sort the DataTable data first, then create the DataTable.  Depending on how you are retrieving the data you can do this pretty easily, (ie. SQL with SORT or ORDER BY statements, etc.)